# Using Pycharm on HPC node - qrsh and run command work around in sh script?

Tags: python, bash, pycharm, remote-debugging

I'm trying to get PyCharm to run on a worker node of a remote HPC cluster. I can only log in to the head node via SSH from PyCharm and from there would usually manually qrsh to a worker node before running the script on the terminal, but I'd like to be able to use the run/debug features of pycharm. I can't debug on my local computer as I'm on Windows and the software is running subprocesses that are for a Linux environment specifically.

I can run via Pycharm using remote config but it would run using the head node. I asked PyCharm support who suggested setting an sh script as remote python interpreter (code I have below). However this hangs pycharm. Running the sh manually I can see that the python only executes after I exit the node and go back to the head node so presumably the next line will only execute on the original node the sh was run from and this is why PyCharm hangs.

Is there any way of executing the python command on the node after qrsh from the script or is this sort of thing simply not possible?

```
#!/bin/sh
qrsh 
exec /path/to/bin/python3.7 $@
```

Comment: How about trying to open pycharm remotely on your cluster using x forwarding?

Comment: Hi thanks for this suggestion - I not sure it it would work with the security set up on my laptop, but I have an alternative option now to just use a different server that I can directly use once I log in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems at present there is no way to get Pycharm to access and use Python on a worker node of the  HPC cluster (though the above answer using forwarding might work for some??). Pycharm support suggested posting a vote on the feature request system

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18828